# HTML table to PPT using PPtxgen

Tags: qlikview, pptxgenjs

I'm using `PptxGen` to create PowerPoint tabular reports of HTML generated in `QlikView` extension. I'm using function `addSlidesForTable` to pass HTML table id.

Syntax below:

```
pptx.addSlidesForTable("tabAutoPaging", {addHeaderToEach:true,master:'MASTER_SLIDE',options:{x:0.4, y:120}} );
```

The master slide is perfectly applied and the header is also printed on each slide. However, `x` and `y` position has no effect of changing the values in the statement above. Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide x and y positions without the options parameter.

Your addSlidesForTable method call should be like

```
pptx.addSlidesForTable("tabAutoPaging1",{addHeaderToEach:true,master:'MASTER_SLIDE', x:0.5, y:3.5} })
```